# How can I get 0 margin between two cells of a table?

Tags: html

I'm trying to get two images adjacent to each other to look like a single image.  This is the HTML I have going:

```
<tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(images/SPIGLogo.png); 
        background-repeat:no-repeat; height: 220px; width: 850px; border:0px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="background-image: url(images/LogoContinuation.png); 
        background-repeat: repeat-x; border:0px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

The image in the right cell is actually a tall, narrow image that is repeated.

The problem is, I am not getting the two cells to look like one when run.  In this image, you can see what it looks like on the left, and what I need it to look like on the right.  There is this "gutter" between them, even when I specify border="0".

[image]

I've seen this done; I am just having trouble reproducing it!

edited to add: BTW, this is a straight HTML page on IE9.

*Following up on the comments to the Accepted answer*: Using CSS to try to achieve the desired result did not work.  Setting the style="border: 0px; border-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px;" gave a reduced size "gutter" between the two images, but that's all.  Perhaps there was more that has to be done?  Anyway, I got the job done using the Accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">...</table>
```

Comment: Well, @powerbuoy, Oltarus's method does work -- perhaps using cellspacing and cellpadding (and I can't believe I forgot about those two properties, makes me feel like a noob) should be deprecated, but they DO work.  You could of course provide the alternate answer rather than just mention CSS.  On another topic entirely, I checked out your blog and I guess I am going to start writing my own WordPress plugin, now that I see how it is done -- thanks for that!

Comment: The `border-spacing` property is not supported by IE7, so using the HTML attribute is more effective. But if you really wish to avoid using the attribute, use `border-collapse: collapse` in CSS.

Comment: @JukkaKKorpela I tried border-collapse: collapse, and while it did reduce the width of the border, it didn't eliminate it like cellpadding/spacing="0" did (even when specifying border: 0px).

Comment: Hmm weird that my comment disappeared. The reason I said "no, blabla" is because Oltarus said "There is only one way", which there isn't. In fact, the way he suggests is deprecated. And also, afaik it _does_ work in IE7, however not in IE6. @Cyberherbalist - border-collapse: collapse; makes the borders collapse. What I suggested was border-spacing: which removes the spacing between cells just like cellspacing does.

Comment: I don't know what happened to your comment, either.  That IS weird.  But in any case, I tried all the alternatives suggested in these comments, and none of them worked.  What did work was what Otarus suggested (and I used to know about these properties too, once upon a time, must be my brain is starting to seize up).